# Multithreading Memory Leak

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a Flask Application that is using multithreading to collect data via thousands of HTTP Requests.

When deploying the Application without multithreading it works as expected, however when I use multithreading there is ~200MB of ram not freed after each run, which leads to a MemoryError.

First I have used queue and multithreading and then repaced it with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor. I have also tried to delete some variables and use garbage collect, but the MemoryError still persits.

This code is not leaking memory:

```
   data = []
   for subprocess in process:  
        result = process_valuechains(subprocess, publishedRevision)
        data.extend(result)
```

This code is leaking memory:

```
    import gc
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    from itertools import repeat
    
    subprocesses = []
    for subprocess in process:  
        subprocesses.append(subprocess)
      
    data = []    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        for res in pool.map(process_valuechains, subprocesses, repeat(publishedRevision)):
            data.extend(res)
            del res
            gc.collect()
```

A simplified version of process_valuechains looks like following

```
def process_valuechains(subprocess, publishedRevision):
    
    data = []

    new_data_1= request_data_1(subprocess)
    data.extend(new_data_1)
    new_data_2= request_data_2(subprocess)
    data.extend(new_data_2)

    return data
```

Unfortunately, even after researching a lot I have no idea what exactly is causing the leak and how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe disabling parts of the code may help. E. g. don't call "request_data_1" but set "new_data_1" to a fixed value and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but if the process_valuechains function is causing the leak, why does the non mulitithreaded version not leak memory?

Comment: What is `process`?

Comment: @user19642323 A valuechain consisting of several business processes represented in JSON format

Comment: I recreated a mocked-up version of your setup and ran it through a [memory profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/). I managed to reproduce higher memory usage at the end of execution with the multithreaded approach compared to the linear approach, but I'm not sure if it was truly due to a memory leak, or rather just an artefact of the overhead of using `ThreadPoolExecutor` or even its `map` function.